# How to get blob file name or extension

Tags: oracle, file, blob, file-extension

I have an existing Oracle database table in which BLOB field contains files, I want to extract the file name and the extension from the BLOB field,

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: I think that's impossible, as the BLOB field only stores the data of the file in binary form. If you need the filename you have to store it in another column of your table...

Comment: Which format is used for storing files in blob? Maybe there are no filename inside

Comment: @MichalSv different formats: documents, images etc, I was thinking if the file header can help in retrieving such information from the stored blob?

Answer (score 8):

`BLOBs` don't have filenames. They're just a string of bytes. They represent the file *contents*, not the file itself. So you will have to either create a column and save the filename when the `BLOB` is inserted (the MIME type is not a bad idea, too), or make one up when you serve it to the user.